# Errors when running tests in parallel

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postgresql-11, django-tests

Multiple issues arise when I try to run tests in parallel.

According to the docs, "test_" is prepended to the database name specified in DATABASES. I used the name "postgres", so the database created when running tests is called *test_postgres*. When running tests in parallel, the following databases are created (which is expected): *test_postgres_1*, *test_postgres_2*, *test_postgres_3*, and *test_postgres_4*. When running all tests with the `--parallel=4` option, however, every test fails with the following message: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "postgres_x" does not exist` where x can be 1, 2, 3 or 4. I can see that the following databases have been created: `test_postgres_x` where x can be 1, 2, 3 or 4. Where's "postgres_x" coming from? Why isn't "test_" being prepended to these?

Furthermore, if I manually create the expected databases `postgres_x` (x = 1 to 4), the migrations applied to the "main" database aren't applied to the clones. This results in errors like this: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_user" does not exist`. Roughly 1/4 tests pass when using 4 cores.

Lastly, if I try to migrate `postgres_x` by using `migrate --database=postgres_x`, I get: `django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection postgres_x doesn't exist`.

I have ensured that all tests are isolated just so I can run them in parallel. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: I'm having the same migration problem. Try to run in parallel and tables are missing i.e. migrations not run. Confusing as I'd assume this would work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building your test harness yourself I suggest using `pytest` and `pytest-django` and `pytest-xdist` this will handle the db creation and migration for each parallel worker. (`pytest` can run Django UnitTest tests without modification)